# Regular Expressions: How to escape the "(" meta char in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am scraping a year value from the innerhtml of a span and the value is in brackets like this:

```
<span class="year_type">(2009)</span><br>
```

I want to get the value of the year without the brackets but am getting some compiler errors when trying to escape the "(" char.

My pattern:

```
const string yearPattern = "<span class=\"year_type\">\((?<year>.*?)\)</span>";
```

Complete Code:

```
const string yearPattern = "<span class=\"year_type\">\((?<year>.*?)\)</span>";
var regex = new Regex(yearPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = regex.Match(data);
return match.Groups["year"].Value;
```

What is the best way to escape the ()

Thanks

Comment: A backslash escapes a string literal for the compiler.  To escape it for the Regex class, you need another.

Comment: There is a great free library called the Html Agility Pack. It will avoid your entire issue, make your code simpler to write and read, and is far less likely to break on HTML edge cases. http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack Please don't parse HTML with regular expressions. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Thanks TueWill - have incorporated it a an hour or so ago and enjoying it. Betters docs would help but getting there. Using basic linq, but not able to use lambda expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use two slashes.

```
const string yearPattern = "<span class=\"year_type\">\\((?<year>.*?)\\)</span>";
```

or the @ literal string operator

```
const string yearPattern = @"<span class=""year_type"">\(?<year>.*?)\)</span>";
```

note; in your original regex you were missing an open-paren.

Comment: Your literal string version won't compile.  When escaping quotes in a literal string, you need to use "", not \".

Answer (score 1):

Prepare to get rocked for parsing HTML with a Regex...

That being said, you just need the `@` in front of your pattern definition (or double your escapes `\\`).

```
const string yearPattern = @"<span class=""year_type"">\(?<year>.*?)\)</span>";
```

Comment: That won't compile.  When escaping quotes in a literal string, you need to use "", not \".

Comment: if you use @-style string literals, you can't use \" for embedded quotes.  Try @"<span class=""year_type"">\(?<year>.*?)\)</span>"

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a character class for this, e.g. `[(]` and `[)]`, but using a double-backslash, e.g. `\\(` and `\\)` (one `\` is for C# and the other one for the regex) is equivalently heavy syntax. So it's a matter of taste.